# google analytics reporting api v4 giving SSL issue

Tags: api, ssl-certificate, analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have the google service account setup and that has my application configured for analytics. I have generated the key and stored key id json file to my PC.

I just want to access my reporting view and simple analytics data using analytics APIs but When I run my Java sample program to get analytics data then it throws

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I know this is caused due to untrusted SSL cert but I don't know which host I should generate cert for and add to the java key store.

Am I missing anything else? I followed the steps mentioned here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java

Also do i need to setup encryption key in my google service account?

Comment: this was solved by setting proxy server and port.

Comment: System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "my.proxy.domain.com");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3129")